# $[a+b]\geq[a]+[b]$ for all a,b belongs to Real number

Tags: inequality

At first I think of triangle inequalities  but it is totally different. Then I consider  that is this bracket symbolize anything in maths or these were just normal square brackets.  I am really not getting anything please help me with the proof.

Comment: If $ a $ is a real number, then there is a unique $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $k \le a <k+1$. Then $[a]:=k.$

Comment: Confirm that your brackets denote the floor function. (If you are asked this, you must be aware.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In usual notation $[x]$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. It is uniquely determined by the inequalities $[x] \leq x <[x]+1$. If $[a]=n$ and $[b]=m$ then $n \leq a <n+1$ and $m \leq b <m+1$. Adding these we get $n+m \leq a+b <n+m+2$. Hence either $n+m \leq a+b <n+m+1$ or $n+m+1 \leq a+b <n+m+2$. This tells us that $[a+b]=n+m$ or $n+m+1$. In either case $[a+b] \geq [a]+[b]$.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull an integer out of the floor function. Then
$$\left\lfloor a+b\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\lfloor a\rfloor+\{a\}+\lfloor b\rfloor+\{b\}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\{a\}+\{b\}\right\rfloor+\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor.$$

It is immediate that

$$\left\lfloor\{a\}+\{b\}\right\rfloor\ge0.$$

---

We can add that equality holds when

$$\{a\}+\{b\}<1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$a+b \geq [a]+[b]$$

**Himt 2** $[a+b]$ is the **largest** integer smaller than $a+b$.

Comment: I don't see how this works. $u\ge v$ and $w\le u$ does not imply $w\ge v$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it works because $\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor$ is an integer $\leq a+b$, so it can't be bigger than the largest integer $\leq a+b$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: agreed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The largest integer with some property is greater or equal than any fixed integer with that property ;)

Answer (score 0):

The floor function is non-decreasing, so

$$\left\lfloor a+b\right\rfloor\ge\left\lfloor\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor\right\rfloor$$

and
$$\left\lfloor\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor\right\rfloor=\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor.$$